# NFS trasfer-rate is too slow

Tags: wireless-networking, nfs

My write speed through NFS mounted in a WiFi LAN is constantly ~65 kB/s. Why? All the examples that I see online are in MB/s and however my WiFi LAN is not so limited.

Details:

I have two notebook connected at the same router in WiFi, both running Ubuntu 12.10. In one of them I installed nfs and added a directory in /etc/exports. In the other one I mounted the directory with 'mount -t nfs ...' I tried with cp shell-command, with copy-paste in nautilus, with dd command but the speed is always the same. 65 kB/s.

After reading nfs tuning guides, I tried to change rsize, wsize in mounting, sync/async in exports but there no improvement.

Where is the bottleneck?

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://serverfault.com/questions/447608/nfs-trasfer-rate-is-too-slow

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, when wifi is involved, the bottleneck is usually the wifi connection.

You could try installing "wifi radar", search "radar" in synaptic, to see which channels are the quietest and set your router to use one of those.